# Select parent element in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to select parent (searchres) in angular and get style to it but I can't do it !
My HTML is this :

```
    <div ng-repeat="product in products" class="searchres">
         <a href="#">
              <img src="{{product.path}}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="{{product.name)}}" />
              {{product.name}}                            
         </a>
    </div>
```

And my code is this :

```
$.each($scope.products, function(index, value) {
      var namePro = value.name; 
      if (namePro.length <= 32) {
          $("body").find(".searchres").css("line-height","50px!important");// is wrong !       
          value.parentNode.css("line-height","50px!important"); // is wrong !       
      }
});
```

what should I do for this problem ?

Comment: what do you want and why don't use ng-style

Comment: I used ng-style : ng-style="product.name.length <= 32 ? {'line-height': '50px !important'} : {}" . but it doesn't work for me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for Javascript code at all in this example. You can use the `ng-class` directive to attach a class to your div under certain conditions.

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products" class="searchres" ng-class="product.name.length <= 32 ? 'your-class-name' : ''">
     <a href="#">
          <img src="{{product.path}}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="{{product.name)}}" />
          {{product.name}}                            
     </a>
</div>
```

Comment: So thanks . I tested it , but it doesn't work for me !

Comment: I tested it myself and apparently you cannot use the `!important` keyword in `ng-style`. My solution would be to create a new CSS class for your custom style. I updated the answer with `ng-class`. This should work.

Comment: Hey , you edited it ! Okay , I put your edited code again .It solved . So Thanks